# Usar Spinner en Fragment

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente proyecto el cual busco hacer llamado al spinner en el SesionFragment.java y al hacer click en el botón "iniciar sesión" en el texto del spinner seleccionado me lleve a otro activity, por ejemplo al seleccionar Secretario(a) me lleve al Activity3Main.java y al seleccionar Tesorero(a) me lleve al Activity4Main.java etc.

**BD usuarios, contraseñas y roles**
[image: Base datos]

**fragment_sesion.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.josue.login.SesionFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/user_fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.105"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.189" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/pwd_fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.177" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtuser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite su Usuario"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.287"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.178" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite su Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.741"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtuser"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.127" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsesion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
        android:text="@string/sesion_fragment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnregistrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/registrar_fragment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnsesion"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/Cargo"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtpwd"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.061" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SesionFragment.java**

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SesionFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
    RequestQueue rq;
    JsonRequest jrq;
    EditText txtUser, txtPwd;
    Button btnSesion, btnRegistrar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sesion, container, false);
        txtUser = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
        txtPwd = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtpwd);

        btnSesion = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnsesion);
        btnRegistrar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnregistrar);
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        btnSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iniciar_sesion();
            }
        });

        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registrar_usuario();
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecto " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inicio de Sesión Exitoso " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        User usuario = new User();
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            usuario.setUser(jsonObject.optString("user"));
            usuario.setPwd(jsonObject.optString("pwd"));
            usuario.setNames(jsonObject.optString("names"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        intencion.putExtra(Main2Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
        startActivity(intencion);
    }
    void iniciar_sesion() {
        String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx/inicio.php?user=" + txtUser.getText().toString() +
                        "&pwd=" + txtPwd.getText().toString();
        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
        rq.add(jrq);

    }

    void registrar_usuario(){
        RegistrarFragment fr=new RegistrarFragment();
        //fr.setArguments(fr);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.escenario,fr)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Ipuc Sesion</string>

    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hermano(a), por favor digite sus datos</string>
    <string name="user_fragment">Usuario:</string>
    <string name="pwd_fragment">Contraseña:</string>
    <string name="sesion_fragment">Iniciar Sesion</string>
    <string name="registrar_fragment">Registrar usuario</string>
    <string name="names_fragment">Nombres: </string>
    <string-array name="Cargo">
        <item>Seleccione su Cargo</item>
        <item>Pastor</item>
        <item>Tesorero(a)</item>
        <item>Secretario(a)</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

[image: Así quedaría el preview]

Comment: Estas intentando mostrar datos de una base de dato MySql, y con android tendrias que mostrar los datos de una basa de datos Sqlite, que la forma que tiene de guardar la información, otra opción seria una una APi y por una petición por Retrofit pudieras mostrar los datos,

Comment: Sí es así, sin embargo lo que busco es llamar desde el SesionFragment.java el spinner para que este me lleve a otro activity. ¿Cómo hago esto posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto logré lo que quería, iniciar sesión usando usuario, contraseña, rol desde una bd externa y de acuerdo al rol se inicie una activity diferente:

Sí se puede optimizar este código les agradezco al grupo de stackoverflow me ayude soy nuevo en esto y me gustaría seguir aprendiendo mucho más. De antemano gracias.

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class SesionFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
    RequestQueue rq;
    JsonRequest jrq;
    EditText txtUser, txtPwd;
    Button btnSesion, btnRegistrar;
    Spinner _spinner;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sesion, container, false);
        txtUser = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
        txtPwd = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtpwd);
        _spinner = (Spinner)vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.Cargo,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        _spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnSesion = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnsesion);
        btnRegistrar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnregistrar);
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        btnSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iniciar_sesion();
            }
        });


        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registrar_usuario();
            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuario - Contraseña y/o Cargo Incorrecto " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inicio de Sesión Exitoso " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        User usuario = new User();
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            usuario.setUser(jsonObject.optString("user"));
            usuario.setPwd(jsonObject.optString("pwd"));
            usuario.setNames(jsonObject.optString("names"));
            usuario.setRole(jsonObject.optString("role"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("pily") && txtPwd.getText
                ().toString().equals("1234") && _spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Tesorero(a)")) {

            Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intencion.putExtra(Main2Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
            startActivity(intencion);


        } else if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("jair") &&
                txtPwd.getText().toString().equals("1234") && _spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Secretario(a)")) {

            Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
            intencion.putExtra(Main3Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
            startActivity(intencion);


        } else if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("jose") &&
                txtPwd.getText().toString().equals("12345") && _spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Pastor")) {

            Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main4Activity.class);
            intencion.putExtra(Main4Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
            startActivity(intencion);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuario - Contraseña y/o Cargo Incorrecto " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    void iniciar_sesion() {

        String url = "https://xxxxx.xxx/inicio.php?user=" + txtUser.getText().toString() +
                "&pwd=" + txtPwd.getText().toString() + "&role=" + _spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
        rq.add(jrq);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

si no te he entendido mal, tendrias que ver el valor que ha selecionado al pulsar por ejemplo el boton de iniciar sesion, y por ejemplo con un switch y con un identificador 1 personal, 2 ventas 3 direccion etc  mandas a un activiti o fragment que quieras algo como esto

```
 public boolean perfil(int perfil) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (perfil) {
        case 1:
            Intent i_login = new Intent(this,activity3.class);
            //o fragment
            startActivity(i_login);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent i2_login = new Intent(this,activity2.class);
            //o framgent
            startActivity(i2_login);
            break;
        case 3:


    }
    return true;
}
```

algo asi

pero los datos los tiene que optener o de una entidad que tu generes que llenes ya sea con un array list o con una base de datos etc. entiendes ??

Comment: Gracias, excelente apreciación, entonces como haría para ingresarlo en mi código. qué me sugieres, ¿elimino el spinner? De antemano gracias.

Comment: Este foro es para responder dudas no para realizar ejercicios,
Te doy unas pistas
Creas una entidad que tengas los atributos que  necesites, id, nombre , descripcion, roll.. etc etc
Hacer una lista en la que le vas dado valores e insertando los objetos que necesites
con los objeres ya creados, creas el spinner con la lista que tenias anteriormente, " puedes encontrar muchos ejemplos de como hacer un spinner en el buscador" 
y con el metodo que te puese de pefil rediriges a la pantalla que quieres.
Con eso mas o menos deberias poder hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias! Jesucristo te continue bendiciendo con tu conocimiento. Eres un crack.